# What are segwit extended key prefix bytes for regtest?

Tags: segregated-witness, bip32-hd-wallets, regtest, xpub

I need the HD version bytes for equivalent of ypub, zpub, Ypub, Zpub but on the regtest network.

I also need Ypub on testnet.

All the rest I can find in [slip132](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0132.md), but it is incomplete.

thanks.